# Conflict between int and string while use of getIntent()

Tags: java, android, string, int

```
if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("3")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("5")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                }
```

actually Price is decimal value but im taking it as string and passing it to next activity. It recives as,

```
String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
```

then Im using that string value to calculate the subtotal as shown below,

```
String quantity = quantityET.getText().toString();

                    double subTotal = 0;

                        subTotal += price * quantity;
```

but im getting this error, The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String. I know why this error is coming but i don't know how to pass and retrieve data between fragments without the use of strings.

I need some help to convert all the string values to integer or help me a way to work this out. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use Double.parseDouble(quantity);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your line of code

```
subTotal += price * quantity;
```

with this code

```
subTotal += (Double.parseDouble(price)) * (Double.parseDouble(quantity));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Code String quantity must be converted to Double before performing 
Arithmetic operation on them

```
String quantity = quantityET.getText().toString();

                double subTotal = 0;

                    subTotal += price * Double.parseDouble(quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your String value to double.Like

```
String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
String quantity = quantityET.getText().toString();


double subTotal = 0;
subTotal += Double.parseDouble(price) * Double.parseDouble(quantity);
```

I hope this will help to you :)